# записать ответ от telegram в файл php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php8

Подскажите, как записать в лог-файл json ответ от telegram, который отображается при запросе в браузере?[image: пример ответа при запросе в адресной строке]

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl . $this->botToken . '/getChatMember?chat_id='.$conversation_chat_id.'&user_id='.$chat_id);
    $res= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $fh = fopen('file.txt', 'a') or die('can\'t open file');
    ((is_array($res)) || (is_object($res))) ? fwrite($fh, print_r($res, TRUE) . "\n") : fwrite($fh, $res . "\n");
    fclose($fh);
```

Пытаюсь использовать данный метод, но на выходе получаю только BOOL(true/false).
Как именно можно записать полный ответ в логи?

[image: скриншот из лог-файла]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю тут дело в `curl` и в том, что возвращает `curl_exec`. Цитата из документации:

> Возвращает **true** в случае успешного выполнения или **false** в случае возникновения ошибки. Однако, если установлена опция **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**, при успешном завершении будет возвращён результат, а при неудаче - **false**.

Comment: Благодарю =)
добавил "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);" и теперь в $res записывается ответ.